# target_compile_options() for only C++ files?

Tags: c++, cmake

Is it possible to use `target_compile_options()` for only C++ files? I'd like to use it for a target that is uses as a dependency for other applications so that the library can propagate its compiler flags to those apps. However, there are certain flags, such as `-std=c++14`, that cause the build to fail if they are used with C or ObjC files.

I've read that I should `CXX_FLAGS` instead to only add those flags to C++ files, however this won't (automatically) propagate through cmake's packages system.

Comment: IIRC `CXX_FLAGS` can be propagated through library packages by [prefixing with that packages name](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html).

Comment: What do you mean by *CMake's package system*?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Solution**

You can do this with [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html):

```
target_compile_options(MyLib PUBLIC $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-std=c++14>)
```

**Alternative**

But the more platform independent way of doing it in this particular case would be to use [`target_compile_features()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html). I'm not sure which [compiler feature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html#prop_gbl:CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES) you're using, so the following is only an example:

```
target_compile_features(MyLib PUBLIC cxx_explicit_conversions)
```

Comment: Great, generator expressions was exactly what I needed, thanks. The target_compile_features does indeed seem nice, although we need to stick with cmake v3.0 for now due to some distros.

Comment: target_compile_features can apparently be used to just directly ask for a particular language version by year, without any need to pick out particular features that that version introduced: target_compile_features(someTargetName PUBLIC cxx_std_14)

Comment: Please don't set C++ standard by manipulating compiler options.  Since cmake 3.1 cmake lets users set the intended compiler standard through target properties by setting the `CXX_STANDARD` property to 11.

Comment: On CMake 3.12 for me this works only if `enable_language(CUDA)` is present in preamble.

Answer (score 0):

> I've read that I should CXX_FLAGS instead to only add those flags to C++ files, however this won't (automatically) propagate through cmake's packages system.

In CMake, if you use any function prefixed with `target_*` it only has the scope of one build target. If you want your whole project to build with given standard you can use `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)`. If some of the targets requires another setting, you can override it locally with the `target` prefixed function and `CXX_STANDARD` variable (it's default value is `${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}`).

As pointed out by [RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8815948/ram) this option is available since v3.1. But judging by https://repology.org/project/cmake/versions it is already widely supported.

It is also often pointed out that you should not set cpp version fixed. I have not formed my opinion on this yet, but you can but you can use the keyword CACHED to make it overridable.